# how to use determine if a String is actually a character in Java?

Tags: java

I need to check if a String is actually a character (only consists of 1 character).

This is what I have so far.

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
String str = keyboard.next();
    if (isChar(str = a) == true)
    {
         System.out.print("is a character");
    }
```

Comment: thanks I couldn't get the formatting to get done was trying to.

Comment: `isChar(str = a) == true` !!! Java do not need `==true`.

Comment: the question is unclear.

Comment: where does the a in ifChar(str = a) come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A (non-null) string can be zero or more characters. So you want to do things like:

```
String str = ...;
if (str != null && str.length() > 0) {
  if (str.charAt(0) == 'a') {
    ...
  } 
}
```

In your question, it is unclear exactly what 'isChar' is, but the code you've written above does not seem semantically correct.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the javadoc for [String](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

```
boolean isChar(String target,String check) {
    if (target != null && check != null){
        return target.indexOf(check) > -1;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use [`String.contains(CharSequence)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29):

```
package so7185276;

import java.util.Scanner;

public final class App {
    /**
     * Check if provided {@link String} contains specified substring
     * (case-sensitive). Print out "{str} contains {what}" if so.
     * 
     * @param str
     *            {@link String} to look into
     * @param what
     *            {@link String} to look for
     */
    private static void isChar(final String str, final String what) {
        if (str != null && what != null && str.contains(what)) {
            System.out.println(str + " contains " + what); // NOPMD (sysout is used)
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        final String str = keyboard.next();
        isChar(str, "A");
        isChar(str, "B");
        isChar(str, "C");
    }

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    private App() {
        // avoid instantiation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure what you want exactly, but one of these options might work for you:

```
String str = keyboard.next();

// If you want to check that the input contains "a"
if (str.contains("a")) {
    System.out.print("a");
}

// If you want to check that the whole input is "a"
if (str.equals("a")) { 
    System.out.print("a");
}
```

If you know the input is one chat, consider using `Scanner.nextByte()`